# OFFSET function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

I have the following formula in a cell:

```
=IF(Q12,ROUND(SUM(Q12:Q18)/7,2),"")
```

Now when I drag it down I want it to calculate SUM for Range Q19:Q25 i.e it should be;

```
=IF(Q19,ROUND(SUM(Q19:Q25)/7,2),"")
```

I believe `OFFSET` is the function to add in the formula but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, `OFFSET` will do this job nicely, but in writing your answer, I have had to make a consideration to the fact that I don't know what offset your formula is to the sum range!

This will do the job, and if your formula isnt in row 1, you'll need the change both of the `row() - 1` statements to offset the formula back to 0 (i.e. if this formula starts in row 12, change `row() - 1` to `row() - 12`

```
=IF(OFFSET($Q$12,(ROW()-1)*7,0),ROUND(SUM(OFFSET($Q$12:$Q$18,(ROW()-1)*7,0))/7,2),"")
```

Having said all of that, you have a conditional (`=If(Q12`) and a sum pointing to the same place, shouldn't you be checking Q12 for some truth, then summing?
I don't know what your data set is though, so I could be talking rubbish.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Aww pnuts, beat me by 19 seconds! Damn this tablet keyboard!

Comment: Thanks @AndrewWynn :)

Comment: Thanks! @pnuts I think I have found a new hobby for public transport. Answering Excel questions without Excel as reference can be a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Taking only the SUM part of your formula and assuming placed in Row1 please try:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(Q$12,7*(ROW()-1),,7,1))
```